# Inner class not included in JAR file after running "jar cf"

Tags: java, jar

I have the following files:

```
java_classes/TerrainMesh.class
java_classes/TerrainMesh$Vertex.class
```

They were compiled from the following source:

```
class TerrainMesh {
  static class Vertex {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

I'm building a JAR file like this:

```
jar cf jar/cities.jar -C java_classes "cities/TerrainMesh.class" -C java_classes "cities/TerrainMesh$Vertex.class"
```

Inspecting the JAR contents with `jar tf jar/cities.jar` gives me:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
cities/TerrainMesh.class
```

As you can see, `TerrainMesh$Vertex.class` is missing from the JAR file. Predictably, when calling methods in `TerrainMesh` that use the inner `Vertex` class, I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. I'm pretty sure this is because the inner class is not included in the JAR.

How do I get the inner class into the JAR file? It seems really weird that `jar cf` is ignoring it.

For what it's worth, I've verified that running `jar tf` on JAR files made by other people *does* show the inner classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to escape the dollar signs when calling `jar cf`:

```
jar cf jar/cities.jar -C java_classes "cities/TerrainMesh.class" -C java_classes "cities/TerrainMesh\$Vertex.class"
```